# activity started by other apps, use existing instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, instance

My app has two activities MainActivity and ExternEntry. ExternEntry gets called by some other app as a way to launch my app. ExternEntry will then call startActivity on MainActivity, which may have already been launched before. My question is, how to resume the MainActivity instance in the background?

Note that this is different from switching activities in the same application. Every time ExternEntry gets called, does it create a new stack as well?

I tried

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(i);
```

and

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
```

in ExternEntry, but both create a new instance of MainActivity.

I also tried setting MainActivity to 'singleTask', but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare launch mode in the android manifest files.

```
<activity
        android:name=".name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
```

i hope it will help you.

Comment: hate to say this but it's the most obvious nonsolution. It should work according to documentation but when I experimented, it still always creates new instance of the activity.

Comment: singleTask means the activity will be in one task. i try it and works.